# java.util.Date has two different outputs?

Tags: java, date, tostring

I have this method:

```
void updatePet(String userid, int index, int happiness, Date lastUpdated, PetLifePhase state, Date created)
```

All calls to it are logged (via a reflection `Proxy`). The arguments are `String.valueOf()`'d and concatenated:

```
updatePet(xxxxxxxx,18,-96,Wed Apr 17 08:10:11 UTC 2013,ACTIVE,2013-04-10 08:01:12.442)
```

Note the output of the two `Date` arguments:

- `lastUpdated`: `Wed Apr 17 08:10:11 UTC 2013` (follows the Javadoc of `Date.toString()`)
- `created`: `2013-04-10 08:01:12.442`

How, why, when, huh? Why does the same method output two different formats? I've looked in the source of this `toString()`, but it's pretty hardcoded to output the first format, there are no `if`s that may decided otherwise.

Comment: 1) Could you provide code that forms logging record 2) how do you call `updatePet`, may be one is a `java.util.Date` while second is `Calendar` 3) Is you call synchronous?

Comment: Are they the same type (class) of Date objects?

Comment: Check your class imports. Are you using the same Date class?

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware (or well, didn't recall at the right time) that java.util.Date subclasses exists. I have a suspicion it may be a java.sql.Date. Going to look into it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your two `Date`s are actually the same type of `Date`?

They may be subtypes of `Date` overriding the `toString()` method differently (such as `Timestamp` which does override `toString()`).

Comment: Alright, switching to JodaTime `DateTime`s internally. At least that class is `final` :p

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `created` is of the subclass Timestamp, which has the format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.fffffffff`.

Answer (score 0):

Almost centainly, you have one parameter which is an instance of `java.util.Date` and another which is an instance of `java.sql.Date` or `java.sql.Timestamp`